# How to calculate the number of automorphisms of this set.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $N = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and define the set of functions 
 $$X = \{ f:N \longrightarrow N : f(i) \leq i\}$$

Similarly let  $S_n$ (the usual symmetric group on $n$ elements) act on $N$ by permuting its elements. I.e. $(\sigma,n) \mapsto \sigma.n   $.   We define a new function $g : N \rightarrow N$ to be $\sigma.N \mapsto \sigma . f(N)$. For example, if 
 $
  f = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 2 & 3
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
and $\sigma  = (12)$ then  $g =  \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 & 3
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) =  \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 3
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \in X$.

We also define an indicator function for all $\sigma \in S_n, f \in X$
 $$
 I(\sigma, f) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $g \in X$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.
  $$

One can think of $I(\sigma,f) = 1$ as an indication of an automorphism of $X$.

Question: Calculate $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\sum_{f \in X}  I(\sigma,f)$.

Although this question can be stated relatively easily it appears rather more difficult to solve.  I am interested in learning a sensible way to approach this problem.

Comment: Is your example of $g = \sigma \circ f$ what you want (also, are you simply composing $f$ and $\sigma$)? Because if I apply $f$ first then apply $\sigma$, I get $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4 \\ 2&1&1&3\end{pmatrix}$. I'm not sure if I understand the process.

Comment: Hi pjs36, no I don't mean $g = \sigma \circ f$.

Comment: To make the example above more specific:  Let $N = \{1,2,3,4\}$, then after applying $f$ to each $i \in N$ we get the set $M = \{1,2,2,3\}$.  Now we apply the permutation $(12)$ to every $i \in M$ to get the set $\{2,1,1,3\}$.  Also note that if we just apply $\sigma$ to $N$ we get the set $\{2,1,3,4\}$.

Comment: Therefore $$g = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 3
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$

Comment: OK, I see now (maybe?). Let's call your operation $\star$, taking a permutation and function from $X$ and producing a function $N \to N$. Is it true that $\sigma \star f = \begin{pmatrix}\sigma(1)&\sigma(2)&\sigma(3)&\sigma(4)\\f(\sigma(1))&f(\sigma(2))&f(\sigma(3))&f(\sigma(4))\end{pmatrix}$? This tends to derange the top row, which you un-derange. Since I want to write your operation as a composition of known functions, I think it ends up being $\sigma \star f = \sigma^{-1} \circ f \circ \sigma$, essentially performing $f$ under a permutation "change of basis".

Comment: Hi pjs36.  Yes I agree with your initial definition of $\sigma \star f$.  However, I do not agree that we can write $\sigma \star f = \sigma^{-1} \circ f \circ \sigma$ although it does work in the example given!

Comment: For example take $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &5 &6 &7 &8&9&10&11\\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 4 &4&6&2&2&4&5&11
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and the permutation $(7,9,10)$.

Comment: I think it should be $g=\sigma\circ f \circ \sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon I was debating if your formula was the correct one; I had a difficult time interpreting the OP's function $g$ as you can see. You are likely correct, although I hoped I was because I felt it would make the change-of-base viewpoint more natural. It seems I should brush up on changes of bases for intuition. I do hope this helps solve the problem at hand, however, because I think it's interesting.